# Does a binary system really emit gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves

In [this essay from Petkov](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/12722/1/Gravitation.pdf), it is stated on page 13 that

> when the stars follow their orbits in the binary system, they do not emit gravitational waves since they move by inertia according to general relativity

**Can anyone offer a verification/critique of this statement?**

The decay of the period of the Husle-Taylor binary is typically taken as the original evidence of gravitational waves. If according to Petkov the binary does not emit GW, then why should the orbits decay?

Comment: This might have to do with the fact that gravitational waves are only emitted in systems with an oscillating quadrupole moment. Two point masses in a binary arrangement have only a dipole moment.

Comment: What then is Petkov's explanation for why the orbital period is getting shorter at *exactly* the rate predicted by GW emission for objects with those masses? Or is that what you are asking - what alternatives could provide such a match?

Comment: @RobJeffries see page 22 of http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/11857/1/GRavitational_Wave_Energy.pdf . This paper notes how in GR no bound solutions of 2 body problem exist and so the period changing of the binary is just what we would expect from GR

Comment: But how good of an explanation this is is unclear to me

Comment: After a quick look ( I didn't have time to read the whole paper) It looks like his arguments claim it would be tidal effects (for the binary system) which would lead to the gravitational radiation. Such effects do indeed cause a deviation from inertial motion, so maybe that's what he meant. The Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave  However has a derivation to 1st order GR for gravitational radiation from a binary treating the masses as point masses sooo....

Comment: @R.Rankin actually he states that although tidal effects would result in some gravitational radiation,  this would be negligibly weak compared to the GW that are believed to be emitted

Comment: That discussion of binary period instability seems to be less than full. If one is going to appeal to that line of argument, then I should have thought that quantitative predictions of what period change is expected from that line of argument would be essential - because the radiation approach does give a result that matches observation. So I think @RobJeffries suggestion that asking what alternatives might explain the Hulse Taylor spindown observations - or even if there are such alternatives - would be a good question. Note that the objection that they raise - that of the fundamental ...

Comment: .... nonlinearity of the EFE doesn't seem to be that strong at a first glance: the Hulse Taylor system outputs a huge amount of energy but the EFE nonlinearity is still pretty weak in this case insofar that a simplish perturbation approach should work - or at least that's how it seems intuitively. Clearly the paper needs a specialist eye for close examination.